# What is the difference between a JsonResponse and a HTTPResponse?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, http

I am following a tutorial and the guy used these two lines of code. I am trying to understand the difference between a JsonResponse and a HttpResponse.

Both the JsonResponse and the HttpResponse leads to the user getting a pop up message (`$.alert({`).

When the output in both cases is an `$.alert({`, I am slightly confused why you need a JsonResponse in one instance and a HttpResponse in another.

```
  if request.is_ajax():
     return JsonResponse({"message": "Thank you for your submission"})
         
    
  if request.is_ajax():
     return HttpResponse(errors, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

**views.py**

```
if contact_form.is_valid():
            print(contact_form.cleaned_data)

    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Thank you for your submission"})
     
if contact_form.errors:
    print("there are errors")
    errors = contact_form.errors.as_json()
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(errors, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

**ecommerce.js**

```
  displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, "", true)
  $.ajax({
    method: contactFormMethod,
    url:  contactFormEndpoint,
    data: contactFormData,

    success: function(data){
      contactForm[0].reset()
      $.alert({
        title: "Success!",
        content: data.message,
        theme: "modern",
      })
      setTimeout(function(){
        displaySubmitting(contactFormSubmitBtn, contactFormSubmitBtnTxt, false)
      }, 500)
    },
    error: function(error){
      console.log(error.responseJSON)
      var jsonData = error.responseJSON
      var msg = ""

      $.each(jsonData, function(key, value){ // key, value  array index / object
        msg += key + ": " + value[0].message + "<br/>"
      })

      $.alert({
        title: "Oops!",
        content: msg,
        theme: "modern",
      })
```

Here is the contact form

[image]

Here is the contact form when you have entered the correct data

[image]

Here is the contact form with an error (in this case the error is that the user has not enetered a Gmail address).

[image]

Comment: Both are HTTP responses, a JSON response will however JSON encode the data, and furthermore it will set the mime_type, etc. of the response in the header. But you can perfectly *emulate* a `JSON` response with a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thank you very much!